# Cannot uninstall hp hotkey support windows 11

Tags: windows, drivers, hp

Hi this morning i received this popup from windows [image]It says: HP hotkey notification display has stopped working and then in the other pop up it says something along the lines of this: "Unable to load a driver on this device", "a security setting has detected a vulnerable driver so it has stopped it from loading. You should fix the settings to load this driver".

So i went to control panel and tried to unistall the program however after giving admin permission to control panel to uninstall it gives a pop up that says "This software isn't supported by this system" and the program remains in the list of the apps in control panel. It is a very light program which i dont use as I have stopped using an HP keyboard and system but the pop up annoys me.

I believe this software wasn't unistalled by me since I have built the PC using an old HDD which was used in an HP system, so it's not malware.

Comment: Try to use [Revo Uninstaller Free](https://www.revouninstaller.com/products/revo-uninstaller-free/) to uninstall the program. Even if the standard uninstallation fails, Revo will let you delete all the registry keys and files of the program. Check the listed items to ensure that everything can indeed be deleted safely.

Comment: It’s part of the Windows image that HP uses, the driver likely was signed by a certificate that is know expired, normally just updating the software should be enough. [Suspect](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c08220813) will be enough to allow you to update the driver then uninstall it

Comment: @harrymc thanks, I just tried and it didn't work.

Comment: @Ramhound Other than the fact that installing additional software when i aim to unistall some is more than unhelpful I doubt that the installation would be succesful as the system said that "This software isn't supported by this system".  I even tried to find the driver in this page https://support.hp.com/it-it/drivers/products however I would need the serial number which i dont have anymore.

Comment: So you tried the software package a linked to or ruled it out without trying it?

Comment: The problem seems to be that you used a boot disk for a computer whose hardware was different than yours. I suggest doing what @Ramhound suggested, because the other alternative is to reinstall Windows from scratch. Question : Is Windows still activated?

Comment: @harrymc I just tried but it doesn't seem to work .  This is quite insane its just a 13MB app am i seriously only allowed to uninstall it via windowds uninstaller?!  In linux i would just shoot some rm -rf and hope to fix.

Comment: @Ramhound I tried following the website and installing the app however i can't really work it out.

Comment: You may of course fire up a Linux Live USB and delete this app. Even if it works, the app risks to return on the next major Windows update.

Comment: @serax - Without futher diagnostics from your end I cannot help you.